# Why is the concat function printing as output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to solve the following hackkerrank question :

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem?isFullScreen=true

I'm getting one abnormality in my solution.

My code:

```
select concat(name, '(', substr(occupation,1,1),')') 
from occupations 
order by name;

select concat('There are a total of ', count(occupation), ' ', occupation,'s.') 
from occupations 
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation), occupation;
```

And I am receiving this line in output alongside the required solution:
[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJGZ.png)

| concat('There are a total of ', count(occupation), ' ', occupation,'s.') |
| --- |
| There are a total of 3 Doctors. |

Can someone explain why am I getting this and how to resolve this?

Comment: This line is the *name* of the column. If you alias the column like:`select concat('There are a total of ', count(occupation), ' ', occupation,'s.') as somename from occupations...` then you will see the name `somename`.

Comment: You might attract more responses if you included everything in the question (but not as links)

Answer (score 0):

First use UNION so the query will be in one lane. Multiple query statements in this case will generate the column name which is 'concat('There are a total of ', count(occupation), ' ', occupation,'s.')'. Secondly use aliases and add ORDER BY at the end of the query so UNION will work.